# MSXML2 to return file format (XML) in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, soap

I make a SOAP call from MS Access using VBA. I do get a response from the webservice. The response is NOT a valid XML file.

Using SoapUI I get the correct result, so the webservice is returning the correct data. However MSXML2 does not return the correct file format (XML) in VBA.

**The code to make the call and parse the XML**

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim Req As Object
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim Resp As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
            
    Set Req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set Resp = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Resp.async = False
    Resp.validateOnParse = False
            
    Req.Open "Post", "https://soap.telematics.tomtom.com/v1.50/objectsAndPeopleReportingService", False
        
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:ser='http://connect.webfleet.tomtomwork.com/services'>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   <soap:Header/>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   <soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      <ser:showObjectReport>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         <aParm>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "            <accountName>****</accountName>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "            <userName>****</userName>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "            <password>****</password>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "            <apiKey>****</apiKey>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         </aParm>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         <gParm>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "            <locale>UK</locale>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "            <timeZone>Europe_London</timeZone>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         </gParm>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         <objectFilter>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "            <object objectNo='102'/>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "            <ungroupedOnly>?</ungroupedOnly>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         </objectFilter>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      </ser:showObjectReport>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   </soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"
    
    Req.send (sEnv)
    
    Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText
    Resp.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:ns3='http://connect.webfleet.tomtomwork.com/services'"
    Debug.Print Req.responseText
    Debug.Print Resp.Text
    
    Dim startNode As Object
    Set startNode = Resp.SelectNodes("//results/resultItem")
            
    Dim NodesOutputLidt() As Variant
    NodesOutputList = Array("odometer/text()")
        
    Dim iObject As Long
    For iObject = 0 To startNode.Length - 1
        Dim iNode As Long
        For iNode = LBound(NodesOutputList) To UBound(NodesOutputList)
            Dim CurrentNode As Object
            Set CurrentNode = startNode(iObject).SelectNodes(NodesOutputList(iNode))(0)
            If Not curretnnode Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox currrentnode.NodeValue
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing to display"
            End If
        Next iNode
    Next iObject
    
    Set Req = Nothing
    Set Resp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**What is expected: *(results returned by SoapUI 5.6)***

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns3:showObjectReportResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns3="http://connect.webfleet.tomtomwork.com/services">
         <return>
            <statusCode>0</statusCode>
            <statusMessage>The operation *showObjectReport* processed succesfully.</statusMessage>
            <errors xsi:nil="true"/>
            <resultSize>1</resultSize>
            <results>
               <resultItem xsi:type="ns4:ObjectReport" objectNo="102" objectUid="1-390874-299CE36476" xmlns:ns4="http://connect.webfleet.tomtomwork.com/transfer/objects">
                  <objectName>DNG100L</objectName>
                  <objectClassName>Vehicle</objectClassName>
                  <objectType>bus</objectType>
                  <lastMsgId>172972612495</lastMsgId>
                  <lastMsgTime>2020-12-11T07:21:30Z</lastMsgTime>
                  <deleted>false</deleted>
                  <position>
                     <latitude>-23658383</latitude>
                     <longitude>27743631</longitude>
                     <mapcode xsi:nil="true"/>
                     <latitudeHumanReadable>23°39'30.1" S</latitudeHumanReadable>
                     <longitudeHumanReadable>27°44'37.0" E</longitudeHumanReadable>
                  </position>
                  <positionText>LBS Depot, R510, Lephalale 0555, ZA</positionText>
                  <positionTextShort>LBS Depot, R510, Lephalale 0555, ZA</positionTextShort>
                  <status>A</status>
                  <driverCurrentWorkState>UNKNOWN</driverCurrentWorkState>
                  <coDriverCurrentWorkState>UNKNOWN</coDriverCurrentWorkState>
                  <driver driverNo="D412" driverUid="1-390874-724B56D2E5"/>
                  <coDriver xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <ignitionState>1</ignitionState>
                  <odometer>1536047</odometer>
                  <tripMode>2</tripMode>
                  <standstillState>0</standstillState>
                  <ignitionTime>2020-12-11T07:20:38Z</ignitionTime>
                  <pndConnected>0</pndConnected>
                  <driverName>MJ MABULA</driverName>
                  <posTime>2020-12-11T07:21:30Z</posTime>
               </resultItem>
            </results>
         </return>
      </ns3:showObjectReportResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**What I get**

```
--uuid:235de702-2fc6-4c5d-8e9a-88a42211f035
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Body><ns3:showObjectReportResponse xmlns:ns3="http://connect.webfleet.tomtomwork.com/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><return><statusCode>0</statusCode><statusMessage>The operation *showObjectReport* processed succesfully.</statusMessage><errors xsi:nil="true"/><resultSize>1</resultSize><results><resultItem xmlns:ns4="http://connect.webfleet.tomtomwork.com/transfer/objects" xsi:type="ns4:ObjectReport" objectNo="102" objectUid="1-390874-299CE36476"><objectName>DNG100L</objectName><objectClassName>Vehicle</objectClassName><objectType>bus</objectType><lastMsgId>172977023791</lastMsgId><lastMsgTime>2020-12-11T11:52:09Z</lastMsgTime><deleted>false</deleted><position><latitude>-23653297</latitude><longitude>27622713</longitude><mapcode xsi:nil="true"/><latitudeHumanReadable>23?39'11.8" S</latitudeHumanReadable><longitudeHumanReadable>27?37'21.7" E</longitudeHumanReadable></position><positionText>Relebogile Stre
et, Lephalale (ZA 0556)</positionText><positionTextShort>Lephalale, Relebogile Street (ZA 0556)</positionTextShort><status>A</status><driverCurrentWorkState>UNKNOWN</driverCurrentWorkState><coDriverCurrentWorkState>UNKNOWN</coDriverCurrentWorkState><driver xsi:nil="true"/><coDriver xsi:nil="true"/><ignitionState>0</ignitionState><odometer>1536286</odometer><tripMode>2</tripMode><standstillState>1</standstillState><ignitionTime>2020-12-11T07:51:39Z</ignitionTime><pndConnected>0</pndConnected><posTime>2020-12-11T11:52:09Z</posTime></resultItem></results></return></ns3:showObjectReportResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:235de702-2fc6-4c5d-8e9a-88a42211f035--
```

Comment: The soap envelope looks pretty okay to me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around to load the XML with the .responseText since the .responseXML is null.

The response is raw information and the first part and last needs removing so just the XML envelope is left, since this will be a static length you can use the LEN function to deducted from starting position 0 to opening < for XML (207) and then the length of the close XML till the end (46) and then use the MID function starting at the first < of the XML, example code below from Req.send (sEnv) in your code.

```
Req.send (sEnv)

Dim XmlMapResponse As String
     
Resp.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:ns3='http://connect.webfleet.tomtomwork.com/services'"
     XmlMapResponse = Req.responseText
'         Debug.Print XmlMapResponse
    Dim strLength As Variant
    strLength = Len(XmlMapResponse) - 253
     XmlMapResponse = Mid(XmlMapResponse, 207, strLength)
'         Debug.Print XmlMapResponse
    If Resp.loadXML(XmlMapResponse) Then

        Dim startNode As Object
        Set startNode = Resp.SelectNodes("//results/resultItem")
        
        Dim NodesOutputLidt() As Variant
        NodesOutputList = Array("odometer/text()")
            
        Dim iObject As Long
        For iObject = 0 To startNode.length - 1
            Dim iNode As Long
            For iNode = LBound(NodesOutputList) To UBound(NodesOutputList)
                Dim CurrentNode As Object
                Set CurrentNode = startNode(iObject).selectNodes(NodesOutputList(iNode))(0)
                If Not CurrentNode Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox CurrentNode.Text
                Else
                    MsgBox "Nothing to display"
                End If
            Next iNode
        Next iObject
        
        Set Req = Nothing
    End If
```

This will then work for any response of any length theoretically.